# error Couldn't find package "@jest/environment@^24.5.0" required by "@jest/reporters@^24.5.0" on the "npm" registry

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I'm completely new to React Native and I'm following Facebook's tutorial at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started using React Native CLI.

Yesterday, I've created a project successfully. Today, when I create an empty folder and run `react-native init AnotherProject` I get:

`error Couldn't find package "@jest/environment@^24.5.0" required by "@jest/reporters@^24.5.0" on the "npm" registry.`

What am I doing wrong? I'm on npm 6.7.0 and node 11.12.0.

Comment: A connection might have dropped mid install, try running the command again

Comment: @webbist probably, though I'd expect to see a more clear error message instead of "package not found in npm registry" it could say something like "connection interrupted, try again".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird. I've ran the *exact same command* again, and it worked.